# Run Script on File Change on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

Anyone know about a program for Mac OS that you can pass the name to an executable and a file to watch, so that it then runs the executable everytime the file being watched changed?

I have something like this in mind:

```
$ fwatch /Users/foo/doc.tex /Users/foo/run-pdflatex.sh &
  fwatch running. Listening for changes in /Users/foo/doc.tex.
$ echo "This aint no LaTeX" > doc.tex
$ fwatch: Change in /Users/foo/doc.tex detected. Running /Users/foo/run-pdflatex.sh...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) which claims to be "a cross-platform file change monitor", and seems to support all the proper platform solutions like Filesystem Events on macOS.

```bash
# Monitor all files in a directory, execute script once when something changes
fswatch -o -r path/to/directory | xargs -n1 -I{} your-command-here
```